# Unity Wait Inside if Statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait

how can i wait if an if statement? I need time to let an audio file play.

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        audio.Play();
       // yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something pretty 'dodgy' like this:

```
  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            audio.Play();
            float timer = 0;
            do{timer += Time.deltaTime;}while(timer != 1)
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

But I would recommend that you actually track the progress of your audio with something in your update loop such as:

```
 if (!audio.isPlaying) { //Audio playing }
```

or

```
if(audio.time > 1) { //Audio has been playing for more than one second }
```

Hope this helps.

Forgot to link...

`audio.isPlaying` = http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-isPlaying.html

`audio.time` = http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-time.html

Comment: Thanks   "if (!audio.isPlaying)" dose that reference the current gameObject  or all audio? fyi i just started learning uniy and c# if you want to see progress its @ deathvenomstudios.com

Comment: It does not reference all audio. (I added some links, which may help as well)